# Using foreach loop to define points and their label in tkz-euclide

Tags: tkz-euclide

**How to use loop in this code to define points and labels**

> ```
> \foreach \x in {1.5,3,...,6}
> ```

MWE

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz-dimline}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\definecolor{fondpaille}{cmyk}{0,0,0.1,0}
\pagecolor{fondpaille}
\color{Maroon} 
%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0]

\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(8,0){B}

\tkzDefShiftPoint[A](0:1.5){A_1}
\tkzDefShiftPoint[A](0:3){A_2}
\tkzDefShiftPoint[A](0:4.5){A_3}
\tkzDefShiftPoint[A](0:6){A_4}

\tkzCompass[color=red,delta=15](A,A_1)
\tkzCompass[color=red,delta=15](A_1,A_2)
\tkzCompass[color=red,delta=15](A_2,A_3)
\tkzCompass[color=red,delta=15](A_3,A_4)

\tkzDrawSegment[thick,brown](A,B)
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B)
\tkzLabelPoints[below](A,B)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this? I changed the `delta` option to `length`, since I use `A` as center for the compass marks.

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz-dimline}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\definecolor{fondpaille}{cmyk}{0,0,0.1,0}
\pagecolor{fondpaille}
\color{Maroon}
%
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0]

    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
    \tkzDefPoint(8,0){B}


    \foreach \x in {1,2,...,4}{%
        \tkzDefShiftPoint[A](0:\x*1.5){A_\x}
        \tkzCompass[color=red,length=.5](A,A_\x)
    }

    \tkzDrawSegment[thick,brown](A,B)
    \tkzDrawPoints(A,B)
    \tkzLabelPoints[below](A,B)
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Edit

To keep the previous point as center for the compass marks you have to define `A_0`.

```
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0]

    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A_0}
    \tkzDefPoint(8,0){B}

    \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \iMoinsUn using int(\i-1)] in {1,2,...,4}{%
        \tkzDefShiftPoint[A](0:\i*1.5){A_\i}
        \tkzCompass[color=red,delta=5](A_\iMoinsUn,A_\i)
    }

    \tkzDrawSegment[thick,brown](A,B)
    \tkzDrawPoints(A,B)
    \tkzLabelPoints[below](A,B)
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```